# How to count misspelled words in a google sheets cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, count, misspelling

Is there a way to count misspelled words in a google sheets cell?

If cell A1 contains 'hello.  ther are a lot of missspelleed wrds in ths cell' and I put the formula in A2, I'd like the formula to return a 4 in A2 for the 4 misspelled words in A1.

I've tried this but only received a 1 in A2:
=SUM(IF(ISERR(SPELLING(SPLIT(A1, " "))), 1, 0))

and this:
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(ISERR(SPELLING(SPLIT(A1, " "))), 1, 0)))

I want to apply the formula to all the cells in one column.

Thanks

Comment: is `SPELLING` a custom function?

Comment: I don't think so. Google Sheets didn't prompt me for parameters when I started typing it in the formula bar. Thanks though.

Comment: I do not thing function `SPELLING` exists in Google Sheets.  You could create a custom function with Apps Script but it will have to use some other service to get this data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native function for testing spelling of text in a spreadsheet.

However, there is a script for a custom formula in GitHub (courtesy of Vance):
https://github.com/caesiumtea/sheets-spellcheck

Load the script and use this formula:
`=counta(split(SPCHECK(A1)," "))`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]